# How to include/import only specific sections when using a multiple file structure

Tags: sectioning, external-files, subdividing

I am writing a rather large document of which I am planning on using multiple input files.  I have previous work that I would like to reuse without copying the data (for purposes of maintainability).

For example, I have a document `linear_algebra.tex`, and I would only like to include the section Eigen Value Decomposition (label `eigenDecomp`).

Is there a package that would allow me only to include the labeled section `eigenDecomp` instead of the whole document?

Thank you

Comment: related: [Speed up compilation by (pre-)compiling chapters separately?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1989/579)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest something that doesn't require extra packages.

Break your document into separate files for each of the sections. Make sure that one of these files is the section you want to show / hide; let's call it `eigenDecomp.tex`, and assume it follows the main section of the document. You can include those files in `linear_algebra.tex`, using `\include{}`. Then, you use the `\includeonly{}` command in the preamble to include only the sections you need.

So, building on the example I gave [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117134/latex-chapters-and-bibliography/117294#117294) for a similar question, you'd do something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\include{introduction}
\include{main}
\include{eigenDecomp}
\include{conclusions}

\end{document}
```

Then, when you only want to include a few sections, you do this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\includeonly{introduction,main,conclusions}    
\begin{document}
```

Note that the only drawback of this is that you can't nest `\include{}` commands, so you might have quite a complex file structure in `linear_algebra.tex`.

There are also other options you could consider such as the package [`Comment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) that allow you to selectively hide or reveal text based on labels.

Comment: Note that `\include` needs to add pagebreaks around the included part, so using it on something lower than a `\chapter` might give unexpected results.